# Creating an oracle view to join values from one or more table

Tags: sql, oracle

So first of all I have two tables,

TABLEA,

```
NAME(PK) COMPONENT_TYPE COMP_STATUS
HEAD1    COLUMN         NOTISSUED
HEAD2    COLUMN         ISSUED
HEAD3    COLUMN         NOTISSUED
HEAD4    COLUMN         NOTISSUED
HEAD5    BRACING        ISSUED
HEAD6    BRACING        ISSUED
HEAD7    BRACING        ISSUED
HEAD6    BRACING        NOTISSUED
```

TABLEB,

```
NAME   PROCESS_STATUS 
HEAD1  0
HEAD2  100
HEAD3  0
HEAD4  0
HEAD5  100
HEAD6  100
HEAD7  0
HEAD6  0
```

And my desired result with view is,

```
COMPONENT_RES TOTAL_COMP ISSUED_QTY COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY
COLUMN        4          1          1
BRACING       4          3          2
```

So the idea is to create a view that has suboperation from different table as well.

I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLEA.COMPONENT_TYPE, 
    SELECT SUM(TABLEA.COMPONENT_TYPE), 
    (SELECT SUM(TABLEA.COMP_STATUS) WHERE COMP_STATUS = 'ISSUED'), 
    (SELECT SUM(TABLEB.PROCESS_STATUS) FROM TABLE B WHERE TABLEA.NAME = TABLEB.NAME) 
FROM TABLEA
```

But it doesnt seem to go nowhere. Please help me....

Comment: What about joining table a with table b first on name(pk) and name? You can then look into using a case statement to code a value as 0 if it is not something you want to count, and use a value of 1 when you do want to count it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the subquery doing inner join and getting the processed status count and using that value in the outer select

Using `case based aggregation` to get the results

```
select A.Component_Type,
       COUNT(A.component_Type) as TOTAL_COMP,
       SUM( case when COMP_STATUS = 'ISSUED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ISSUED_QT,
       MAX(T.COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY) as COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY
from tableA A
join ( select A.Component_Type, 
              SUM( case when  PROCESS_STATUS =100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY
       from tableA A
       join TableB B
       on A.name = B.NAME
       group by A.component_Type
       ) T
ON A.Component_Type= T.Component_Type
group by A.component_Type, T.Component_Type
order by A.component_Type desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that TABLEA.NAME is PK column. But the sample data contains duplicate values in TABLEA.NAME column. If that is for sure a PK column then the following query should work else the result column COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY would'nt work. Check it.

```
SELECT MAIN_TABLE.COMPONENT_TYPE COMPONENT_RES,
   COUNT(1) TOTAL_COMP,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA WHERE COMP_STATUS = 'ISSUED' AND COMPONENT_TYPE = MAIN_TABLE.COMPONENT_TYPE) ISSUED_QTY,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA,TABLEB  WHERE TABLEA.NAME = TABLEB.NAME AND PROCESS_STATUS = 100 AND TABLEA.COMPONENT_TYPE = MAIN_TABLE.COMPONENT_TYPE  GROUP BY TABLEA.NAME,TABLEA.COMPONENT_TYPE) COMPLETED_PROCESS_QTY
  FROM TABLEA  MAIN_TABLE
 GROUP BY COMPONENT_TYPE
```

Comment: Dinesh i made a mistake. on table a it should be HEAD8